# Binding keys for Urban Terror on Mac

Tags: urban-terror

I'd like to have some custom binds while playing Urban Terror, but they don't (always) work.

I have **q3config.cfg** in

```
[HOME]/.Library/Application Support/Quake3/q3ut4/q3config.cfg
```

and **autoexec.cfg** in my q3ut4 folder (Applications).

I've tried modifying both but nothing works. Or rather, what happens is that the first time I set it they usually work, but when I restart my computer/quit the game and reopen it (not sure which is the factor here), they stop working except the bind I made for the Knife on the letter X.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Try adding +exec autoexec.cfg to the shortcut you're using to launch the game, to ensure that the autoexec.cfg file is definitely being loaded (this is apparently a known intermittent issue) and then put all your key bindings into the autoexec.cfg file

Comment: @kalina I don't use any shortcuts actually. :P But how would I do that, there's isn't an easy way to do that on the Mac, unless you use the Terminal I guess.